# Return value coming through as undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

If I console.log the output from count+1, I get a correct number value. If I output the value of note.note_id, I get undefined. Why is this?

I have tried setting value to a predefined one inside the function.

```
note.note_id = db.notes.count(function(err, count) {
  return count + 1;
});
```

Comment: We'll need to see more context -- for instance, what does `db.notes.count` do? Since it's *that* function, not the one in the expression you've shown, that will determine what `note.note_id` gets back.

Comment: It's a function from MongoDB (notes is my collection): http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to answer without knowing what `db.notes` is but it seems to be something accessing a database. This means it's most likely asynchronous which meansa that the `count()` method will never return a value but you need to do whatever you want to do with the result inside the callback.

```
db.notes.count(function(err, count) {
    note.note_id = count + 1;
    // do more stuff here
});
// do NOT do stuff here. it will run BEFORE the callback has been executed
```

Comment: I see, this has potential. I am saving it to database before that function has had time to set it.

Comment: You were right. Callback didn't complete, so when I saved the object to database, the return was "undefined". I moved my save to inside the callback, which solved the issue. Thanks!